# Функция php, выводящая поддерживаемые алгоритмы хеширования

Tags: алгоритм, функции, шифрование

100% есть такая. Я давненько использовал ее. Она выдает *массив* с названиями алгоритмов хеширования, НО я не могу вспомнить название.

В старых архивах наверное есть, но когда она использовалась - не помню. каждый бэкап просматривать не хочу.

Подскажите название. В гугле ищу - ненахожу :(

---

[Подскажите аналог функции password_verify](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527913/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-password-verify)

[Функция php, выводящая поддерживаемые алгоритмы хеширования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526456/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-php-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%85%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

[когда password_hash() вернет ошибку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601880/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-password-hash-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел! http://php.net/manual/ru/function.hash-algos.php

hash_algos — Возвращает список зарегистрированных алгоритмов хеширования