# Подскажите аналог функции password_verify

Tags: php, хеширование, password-hash

Вчера-позавчера где-то видел функц рядом с password_verify. Называется, кажется, password_equals.

Но найти не могу.

---

2модератор: Ошибку исправил. Я уже решил проблему - опять самому отвечать на вопрос?

---

[Подскажите аналог функции password_verify](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527913/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-password-verify)

[Функция php, выводящая поддерживаемые алгоритмы хеширования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526456/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-php-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%85%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

[когда password_hash() вернет ошибку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601880/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-password-hash-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел: **hash_equals**  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.hash-equals.php
Сравнивает две строки хеша. Должна использоваться при тестировании хешей, полученных фукнцией crypt().

crypt() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.crypt.php - осуществляет необратимое хеширование строки.

---

Но hash_equals *не является* аналогом password_hash. Я не мог найти информацию про password_equals, потому что такой функции нет.