# когда password_hash() вернет ошибку?

Tags: php, обработка-ошибок, password-hash

В каких случаях password_hash() возвратит ошибку? Я додумался только до одного случая: если на сервере нет запрошенного (указанного в функции) алгоритма шифрования.

Так ли это? И в каких еще случаях будет возвращать ошибку?

---

[Подскажите аналог функции password_verify](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527913/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-password-verify)

[Функция php, выводящая поддерживаемые алгоритмы хеширования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526456/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-php-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%85%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

[когда password_hash() вернет ошибку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601880/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-password-hash-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Залезем в исходник функции](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/49412756df244d94a217853395d15e96cb60e18f/ext/standard/password.c#L358), это не так страшно как кажется.

В основном, ошибки будут возвращаться при неверном вызове функции. Например, вы верно подумали, метод хэширования указан неверно. Или параметр cost вне допустимых пределов. Много проверяется уже deprecated параметр salt.

Интересна проверка, что если `crypt` сгенерирует NULL или результат меньше 13 байт, то это тоже является ошибкой и будет возвращено `false`. А вот когда `crypt` может такое сделать - никак не задокументировано ([и enSO это подтверждает](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745272) со ссылкой на пару багрепортов), а я слишком слаб в криптографии, чтобы раскурить его исходник.

Comment: хм-м... ну я все таки включу  проверку "ошибочности" в код, а то вдруг...

Comment: пробовал ставить cost 50 - выдает ошибку. имеется вопрос: какой максимум можно ставить для бкрипт? Лично у меня уже на 15 вылазит ошибка. Но  даже при значении 13 время генерации хеша пароля больше 30 секунд. Нужно еще раз протестировать..

Comment: От 4 до 31, как написано в исходнике. Дефолт вроде бы 10. Да, cost для того и нужен, чтобы резко поднимать сложность вычисления хеша пароля. Если у вас нет особых требований к сложности хэша, оставьте значение дефолтным.

Comment: ВИЖУ!!! "if (cost < 4 || cost > 31) {" только странно то что в  яндекс уроках было сказано, что сколько хочешь, столько и можно ставить cost. И я вообще в шоке (немножко) от того что есть возможность глянуть в sourceCode. Так некоторые вопросы отпадают (например про cost).